# .NET 6 Integration Test running twice when only one should occur

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-6.0, xunit

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app I am trying to integration test. I have the integration test running but a strange output is occurring that I can't figure out why.

The part I am trying to integration test is when a request occurs, the application generates a file in a specific directory.

The program generates the file, but after completing the test, another file appears a second or so later with the same data.

I changed my application code to generate a file with the thread number that was being executed and it gave off two files with different numbers.

I ran the code without the integration test and confirmed it doesn't occur normally.

Breakpointing via Visual Studio only ever caught the first instance and never the second.

My web app project file looks like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MyIntegrationProject" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My integration test project file looks like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MyWebApp.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="appsettings.Test.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have the created a custom web application factory:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
            string projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string configPath = Path.Combine(projectDir, $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(configPath);
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, servicesCollection) =>
        {
            var dbContextDescriptor = servicesCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>));

            servicesCollection.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

            var dbConnectionDescriptor = servicesCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbConnection));

            servicesCollection.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor);
            servicesCollection.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(""));
        });

    }
}
```

The test code:

```
public class MyTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public MyTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ATest()
    {
        // Arrange
        HttpClient client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/v1.0?id=1", null);

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before and knows what would cause it?

Comment: _"Breakpointing via Visual Studio only ever caught the first instance and never the second."_ - that tells me that the second instance is running outside of VS - are you using the `dotnet` command-line tool while _also_ using VS? If so, that might explain it. I might suggest putting `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` so that when _either_ the VS-attached or the not-attached instance hits that point you'll get a popup prompt to attach and step-through.

Comment: Have you tried running tests with `dotnet test`? Does it lead to the same issue?

Comment: @GuruStron dotnet test only gives off one file as expected. Whereas running through test explorer in VS gives off two.

Comment: @UncountedBrute then I would assume that there is an issue with VS and maybe it not worth to bother that much.

Comment: @GuruStron quite possible. Thanks everyone for your help.